# If rowCount > 5 stop the loop PDO PHP

Tags: php, loops, pdo

I'm working with PDO and I want to loop database records in an array.

```
//Something like this
<?php 

    <?php
    $query= $DbConnect->prepare("SELECT * FROM office_app ORDER BY id DESC");
    $query->execute();
    $querynumber = $query->rowCount();
    $queryrecords= $query->fetchAll();


            foreach ($queryrecords as $records) {
            ?>
                <tr align="center">
                    <td><?php echo $records["Date"] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $records["Information"] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $records["Debit"] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $records["Credit"] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $records["Ballance"] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $records["IPADDRESS"] ?></td>
                </tr>

            <?php
            }
    echo $queryrecords;
    ?>
```

currently `echo $queryrecords` returns 7 (I have only 7 input at my table). The main thing is I want my user to display only 5 of the newest records something like pagination but not. Is there an easy way to do that?

I tried `for` loop but it didn't work (or I couldn't do it properly)

```
for($i = 0; $i<=5; $i++){
     foreach($queryrecords as $records){
       <?php echo $records['...'] ?>
   }
}
```

I'm really confused at the moment... How do I define `rowCount` as `$i` or does it even work? Because it doesn't make sense when you think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Returning all rows and then limiting them via PHP is extremely inefficient. Instead, you should limit the number of records being returned by SQL in the first instance using the `LIMIT` clause:

```php
$query = $DbConnect->prepare('
    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM 
        office_app 
    ORDER BY 
        id DESC 
    LIMIT 5
');
```

Comment: can you please delete your answer.